# Unable to use HikariCP in Spring Boot 1.5.18 with multiple data source configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We are using multiple datasource configuration in our spring boot app.
both dataasources belongs to mysql only.

Configured multiple data source using:

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

**pom.xml changes:**

```
<!-- exclude tomcat jdbc connection pool, use HikariCP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- exclude tomcat-jdbc, Spring Boot will use HikariCP automatically -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**.properties****:**

```
spring.db1.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.db1.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.db1.datasource.username=root
spring.db1.datasource.password=

spring.db2.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.db2.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.db2.datasource.username=root
spring.db2.datasource.password=
```

**Datasource Bean Config:**

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db1.datasource")
public DataSource db1DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}


@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db2.datasource")
public DataSource db2Source() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

But when I ran it Got following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: use `url` instead of `jdbcUrl` in your properties file.

Comment: @M.Deinum Same exception. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.

Comment: Your setup seems to be OK. Are you passing your params in `application.properties` or is it a different file name. Also I noticed you have not included db driver in the pom for mysql

Comment: You should use `url` as mentioned before and also try removing the `driverClassName` property as that isn't needed (Spring Boot will figure it out based on the URL instead). Could you also add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. removed driverClassName, its working

Answer (score 0):

You are missing driver dependencies in your pom

You need to add below lines to your pom.xml to include the database driver.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```